# Хранение сессий

Tags: php

Доброго времени суток! Как хранить сессии стандартными средствами PHP или в БД? Часто замечаю что в cms сессии хранят в БД. В каких ситуациях использовать хранение в БД ? И какие из этого вытекают плюсы и минусы? Если у кого нибудь есть ссылка на статью где подробно сравниваются два этих метода скиньте ее.Всем огромное спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если сравнивать хранение в БД и в файловой системе...

Видимые мной плюсы:

- Упрощение чистки за счет использования индексов (как правило, реляционные или документ-ориентированные БД) или автоматической чистки ключей (как правило, key-value БД).
- Если БД реляционная — возможность связей других сущностей с сессиями. Закрылась сессия, удалился ряд — за счет `ON DELETE CASCADE` автоматически вычистились и связанные объекты.
- Большая безопасность для shared-хостингов, где, в случае неправильной конфигурации сервера можно получить доступ к файлам с данными сессий, или, как минимум, перечислить их имена (идентификаторы).
- Если сериализация самодельная или в распространенный формат, то можно разделять сессии между несколькими подсистемами, в том числе, реализованными и на разных языках и технологиях.

Видимые мной минусы:

- В зависимости от БД скорость работы с сессиями может оказаться значительно ниже, замедлив загрузку страниц. Скажем, в PostgreSQL я бы ложить сессии стал только по серьезно обоснованной необходимости. Если БД делает какие-то гарантии надежности хранения, то, возможно, она только тратит лишнее время.
- Малополезная информация в БД может приводить к ее излишнему разрастанию. Сессии живут не особо долго — данные, по сути, эфемерны. Скажем, с in-memory БД (например, MemcacheDB, Redis) на букально небольшом количестве активных посетителей, которые не хотят принимать cookies (роботы хорошо подходят), легко можно бесполезно потерять довольно много памяти. Добиться дефрагментации и высвобождения-отдачи ее назад системе может оказаться не самой легкой задачей.

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос ваш, увы, слишком, как бы это сказать..... частный. Я вот, например, в одном из проектов хранил сессии в БД исключительно ради того, чтобы было бы легче отслеживать количество пользователей онлайн и как "средство" для автологина. В других случаях обходился и без этого. Частный случай.

Answer (score -1):

один из плюсов хранения сессии в БД - это масштабируемость. Еще скорость чуть чуть возрастает (скорость генерации страницы). Да и параноики эту тему не обошли, "безопасней" всё-таки.